# How to change the custom error message on delete operation in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a validation before one kind of item gets deleted in RailsAdmin:

```
 before_destroy :dont_delete_master_list

 def dont_delete_master_list
    if name == MASTER_LIST_NAME
      errors.add :base, "You can't delete a Master List"
      throw(:abort)
    end 
  end
```

I want to show this custom message on the rails admin view: "You can't delete a Master List" but instead I am getting:

[image]

How can I customize the error message in RailsAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to switch to use a validation with a custom message

```
validate :dont_delete_master_list

 def dont_delete_master_list
    if name == MASTER_LIST_NAME
      errors.add :base, "You can't delete a Master List"
      throw(:abort)
    end 
  end
```

You might not want to run this validation outside of rails admin. If thats the case you can add a virtual field that's only present on a rails admin form. You could do this

```
attr_accessor :edited_on_rails_admin

rails_admin do
  edit do
    field :edited_on_rails_admin, :hidden do
      virtual?
      default_value true
    end
  end
end
```

And then use the value on your validation

```
validate :dont_delete_master_list, if: edited_on_rails_admin
```